# Requests.get giving wrong status code for my URL

Tags: url, python-requests

Got some URLs which I'm testing using the requests library. Example code can be found below:

```
page = requests.get(url)
print (page.status_code)

#output: 200
```

Some URLs returns a 404 status code when tested manually. Why is the output giving 200 then?

Answer (score 2):

The programmer can define the status code manually. And it may have misled you.

the HTTP status code “200”, means is “file found.” if you redirect to another page, you will get 200 status code

So You do not let your request redirects.

```
r = requests.get('http://example.com/sdfsdfs', allow_redirects=False)

print(r.status_code)
```